# What type of stemware is this?

Tags: cocktails, glassware

I've recently inherited a set of these glasses and I can't seem to figure out what type of glass/stemware they are and what cocktails are traditionally served in them (if any). Picture attached, jigger for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are probably dessert wine glasses for sherry or port.
Today they usually have a longer stem, especially mondern designs, but in the past, there were quite a few short stem sherry glasses and often also with such a knob in the stem (see attached images)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, right, agreed!!